# Java HTTP Client Request with defined timeout

Tags: java, http, timeout, network-protocols

I would like to make BIT (Built in tests) to a number of server in my cloud. I need the request to fail on large timeout.

How should I do this with java?

Trying something like the below does not seem to work.

```
public class TestNodeAliveness {
 public static NodeStatus nodeBIT(String elasticIP) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
  HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
  client.getParams().setIntParameter("http.connection.timeout", 1);

  HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet("http://192.168.20.43");
  HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

  System.out.println(response.toString());
  return null;
 }


 public static void main(String[] args) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
  nodeBIT("");
 }
}
```

-- EDIT: Clarify what library is being used --

I'm using httpclient from apache, here is the relevant pom.xml section

```
 <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
   <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
   <version>4.0.1</version>
   <type>jar</type>
 </dependency>
```

Comment: What library are you using for all of the HTTP functionality?

Answer (score 123, accepted):

```
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;

...

    // set the connection timeout value to 30 seconds (30000 milliseconds)
    final HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 30000);
    client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
```

Comment: What does this do? A timeout of what does it set? Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3000767/apache-httpclient-coreconnectionpnames-connection-timeout-does-nothing

Comment: Apache's HttpClient has two separate timeouts: a timeout for how long to wait to establish a TCP connection, and a separate timeout for how long to wait for a subsequent byte of data. HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout() is the former, HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout() is the latter.

Comment: What is the default timeout? Is it 0=infinite?

Comment: http.connection.timeout
Integer
The timeout until a connection is established. A value of zero means the timeout is not used.

Comment: To future readers: It should be noted that the classes referenced here are now deprecated (as of 2016-07-05), though this was probably a good answer when it was posted in 2010. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19153314/192801 for something a bit more current.

Answer (score 138):

If you are using Http Client version 4.3 and above you should be using this:

```
RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom().setConnectTimeout(30 * 1000).build();
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig).build();
```

Comment: Thanks! I spent 20 minutes at least trying to figure out how to get rid of the deprecated commands to do this before finding your answer.

Comment: Forgot `SocketTimeout`. Also, does "default" mean it's default for all `HttpClient` that the `HttpClientBuilder` from create() will give through `build()` method? Or just the ones that pass through `setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig)`? *Am I making sense?*

Comment: @ADTC Your question is a bit confusing :). The default request config will be used for all HttpPost, HttpGet,... instances using 'only' that HttpClient. If you made another HttpClient instance then this request config will not be used with that client.

Answer (score 41):

HttpParams is deprecated in the new Apache HTTPClient library. Using the code provided by Laz leads to deprecation warnings.

I suggest to use RequestConfig instead on your HttpGet or HttpPost instance:

```
final RequestConfig params = RequestConfig.custom().setConnectTimeout(3000).setSocketTimeout(3000).build();
httpPost.setConfig(params);
```

Comment: *"using the code above"* << SO is not a forum and answers move up/down due to several factors, so we don't know which code you're referring to. Could you say something like "using the code from xyz's answer"?

Comment: Btw, neat answer. But when compared to Thunder's answer, what's the difference between setting the `RequestConfig` into every `HttpPost` as opposed to setting it as default into the `HttpClient`?

Comment: Yes, you are right, the code Above refers to the "accepted answer" which shouldn't change in time. I will update my answer anyway..

Answer (score 11):

It looks like you are using the HttpClient API, which I know nothing about, but you could write something similar to this using core Java.

```
try {

   HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
   con.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
   con.setConnectTimeout(5000); //set timeout to 5 seconds
   return (con.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK);

} catch (java.net.SocketTimeoutException e) {
   return false;
} catch (java.io.IOException e) {
   return false;
}
```

Comment: This will not affect the timeout for Apache HTTP Client.

Comment: HttpURLConnection's notion of timeout is insufficient. If the server begins to respond, but then hangs, the timeout is never reached. Apache's HttpClient is a better choice because of this difference.

Answer (score 10):

The said method with highest up's by Laz is deprecated from version 4.3 onwards. Hence it would be better to user the Request Config Object and then build the HTTP Client

```
    private CloseableHttpClient createHttpClient()
        {
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient;
        CommonHelperFunctions helperFunctions = new CommonHelperFunctions();
        PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager cm = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
        cm.setMaxTotal(306);
        cm.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(108);
        RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
            .setConnectTimeout(15000)
            .setSocketTimeout(15000).build();
        httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
            .setConnectionManager(cm)
            .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig).build();
        return httpClient;
        }
```

The PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager is user to set the max default number of connections and the max number of conncetions per route. I have set it as 306 and 108 respectively. The default values will not be sufficient for most of the cases.

**For setting Timeout:**
I have used the RequestConfig object. You can also set the property Connection Request Timeout for setting timeout for waiting for connection from Connection manager.

Answer (score 7):

I found that setting the time out settings in `HttpConnectionParams` and `HttpConnectionManager` did not solve our case. We're limited to using `org.apache.commons.httpclient` version 3.0.1.

I ended up using an `java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService` to monitor the `HttpClient.executeMethod()` call.

Here's a [small, self-contained example](http://sscce.org/)

```
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.EntityEnclosingMethod;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.multipart.FilePart;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.multipart.MultipartRequestEntity;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.multipart.Part;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

/**
 * @author Jeff Kirby
 * @since <pre>Jun 17, 2011</pre>
 */
public class Example {

   private static final String SITE = "http://some.website.com/upload";
   private static final int TIME_OUT_SECS = 5;

   // upload a file and return the response as a string
   public String post(File file) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      final Part[] multiPart = { new FilePart("file", file.getName(), file) };
      final EntityEnclosingMethod post = new PostMethod(SITE);
      post.setRequestEntity(new MultipartRequestEntity(multiPart, post.getParams()));
      final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
      final List<Future<Integer>> futures = executor.invokeAll(Arrays.asList(new KillableHttpClient(post)), TIME_OUT_SECS, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      executor.shutdown();
      if(futures.get(0).isCancelled()) {
         throw new IOException(SITE + " has timed out. It has taken more than " + TIME_OUT_SECS + " seconds to respond");
      }
      return post.getResponseBodyAsString();
   }

   private static class KillableHttpClient implements Callable<Integer> {

      private final EntityEnclosingMethod post;

      private KillableHttpClient(EntityEnclosingMethod post) {
         this.post = post;
      }

      public Integer call() throws Exception {
         return new HttpClient().executeMethod(post);
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This was already mentioned in a comment by [benvoliot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/87696/benvoliot) above. But, I think it's worth a top-level post because it sure had me scratching my head. I'm posting this in case it helps someone else out.

I wrote a simple test client and the `CoreConnectionPNames.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT` timeout works perfectly in that case. The request gets canceled if the server doesn't respond.

Inside the server code I was actually trying to test however, the identical code never times out.

Changing it to time out on the socket connection activity (`CoreConnectionPNames.SO_TIMEOUT`) rather than the HTTP connection (`CoreConnectionPNames.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT`) fixed the problem for me.

Also, read the Apache docs carefully: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/params/CoreConnectionPNames.html#CONNECTION_TIMEOUT

Note the bit that says

> Please note this parameter can only be applied to connections that are bound to a particular local address.

I hope that saves someone else all the head scratching I went through. That will teach me not to read the documentation thoroughly!

Answer (score 3):

Op later stated they were using Apache Commons HttpClient 3.0.1

```
 HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.getHttpConnectionManager().getParams().setConnectionTimeout(5000);
        client.getHttpConnectionManager().getParams().setSoTimeout(5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

`HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, 10*60*1000);// for 10 mins i have set the timeout`

You can as well define your required time out.