# I need aliveness test library for HTTP Servers

Tags: java, testing, networking, monitoring, high-availability

I'm writing a monitor service for our EC2 based cluster, it task will be [connect via HTTP/S to our events servers each X(ms), verify they are alive, rest].

I need a toolkit that will be able to perform the Connect test itself and report success or failure. I've tried to do this with [Apache HTTPClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3000767/apache-httpclient-coreconnectionpnames-connection-timeout-does-nothing) but I'm getting too many false positives on failures which did not happen. I've also looked at JMeter which at first looked quite promising but after downloading a 15mb file with ~25 3rd party jars started to feel like a huge overkill.

The requirement is simple: Check that tested node replies correctly in a defined time frame on HTTP GET request.

Could you suggest a library that allows this service? It is crucial to keep the false positive rate into a bare minimum because hmmm... well that means our processing stops until a broken node is examined... (A no-no indeed :)

Thank you,
Maxim.

Comment: Can you explain further what the problems with httpclient were? It should work fine for this use case.

Comment: HTTPClient as a client has no problems. Yet and HTTP Aliveness library needs to be able to allow reconnection if node failed, it should perhaps has aliveness verification schemes (aggressive recheck just once in small delay or relaxed allow 30 seconds in which 2 attempts should successes). What I'm saying is HTTPClient is too low level for the purpose aliveness tests framework.

Answer (score 0):

For something in a Unix environment (which I'm guessing is what you are using because you are using Apache), try Monit http://mmonit.com/monit/

You can use Monit to make requests to your services, expect certain content and then create alerts based on what it thinks the state of the service is. Here's an example of a config file that can be used to monitor Apache: http://mmonit.com/wiki/Monit/ConfigurationExamples#apache

You can install Monit on each of your boxes and then use M/Monit to monitor of your monitored boxes.