# How to Debug HttpRequestExecutor.execute(request, connection, context);.?

Tags: java, httprequest, httpresponse, apache-httpclient-4.x

The below lines of code

```
HttpRequestExecutor httpexecutor = new HttpRequestExecutor();
HttpResponse response2 = httpexecutor.execute(request2, conn, context);
log.info("Status Line "+response2.getStatusLine());
```

while executing the second statement my request/response is blocked by proxy. How to debug this.?
While the same statement executing from my local environment where no proxy is configured, am able to see 
the log returns the below code
"Status Line HTTP/1.1 200 OK"

Comment: Not sure what your question is exactly - what are you trying to debug?  Or are you asking about how to set up proxy server configuration in HttpRequestExecutor?  For general debugging of HTTP stuff, I'm a big fan of the Live HttpHeaders plugin ( https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/ ) for firefox, but I can't tell if that is what you are asking about or not.

Comment: Hi Kevin, my question here is how to get to know whether "httpexecutor.execute(request2, conn, context);" is successfully sent the request through proxy server and able to get the response.? or it got blocked while sending the request or at receiving response.?

Comment: ok - so what happens when you do the call when there is a proxy server involved?  Does the call to execute() literally block (like your application hangs)?

Comment: Yes Kevin, I am calling this execute() method (which is in a JAVA class) through JSP page, while rendering it shows a processing forever.

Comment: ok - sounds like you need to set a timeout - I'll post a link to reference about this in an official answer

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is to set a timeout on the request - basically telling the executor to give up if no connection can be established within a certain period of time.

This SO article covers this: [Java HTTP Client Request with defined timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3000214/java-http-client-request-with-defined-timeout)

the accepted answer has important information about the fact that Apache's implementation has two timeouts - be sure to read that.

Note that it won't be possible for you to actually distinguish between a connection failure that was caused by some other problem - all you will know is that your attempt timed out.  In your response to the user, you'll probably wind up saying "Unable to connect to host XXXXX.  Possible causes are that your Internet connection is down, or that you have a proxy server that prevents outbound connections to that host."