# Apache HTTP components: Set timeout on default client

Tags: java, timeout, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

I'm creating a default HTTP client using `HttpClients.createDefault()`, but I'd like to change the default timeout (it seems pretty long, it's been over a minute now and it didn't time out).

Is it possible to change only the timeout of the default client or do I have to build the client from scratch?

I'm using version 4.3.3 of the apache HTTP client.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3000214/java-http-client-request-with-defined-timeout

Comment: @robermann I've checked the code in that answer. Using the code example there gives me deprecated warnings in eclipse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
HostConfiguration hostCfg = new HostConfiguration();
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpMethod method = new GetMethod("... your get query string");

int timeout = 5000; //config your value
method.getParams().setSoTimeout(timeout);

//the call
client.executeMethod(hostCfg, method);
```

Or you can set the timeout in [HttpConnectionParams](https://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/params/HttpConnectionParams.html#setSoTimeout%28int%29).

**EDIT**

With HttpClient = 4.3, from the [official documentation](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html#d5e473):

```
HttpClientContext clientContext = HttpClientContext.create();
PlainConnectionSocketFactory sf = PlainConnectionSocketFactory.getSocketFactory();
Socket socket = sf.createSocket(clientContext);

int timeout = 1000; // ms <-- 

HttpHost target = new HttpHost("localhost");
InetSocketAddress remoteAddress = new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByAddress(new byte[] {127,0,0,1}), 80);
sf.connectSocket(timeout, socket, target, remoteAddress, null, clientContext);
```

Comment: Is it possible that this is for version 3.x of the apache client? I'm using version 4.3.3, should have mentioned that - my bad :(

Comment: I'm still getting the deprecated warning ("The type HttpParams is deprecated" for example)

Comment: HttpClient is really heavily changed. Added a 4.3's example code

Comment: Thanks for the 4.3 example. I've also found a solution using the RequestConfig method `setConnectionTimeout`, and assigning that config using the method `setConfig` on the httpget object :)

Answer (score 9):

Why using the default client when timeouts are easily configurable for custom clients? The following code does the job for **httpclient 4.3.4**.

```
final RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
    .setConnectTimeout(CONNTECTION_TIMEOUT_MS)
    .setConnectionRequestTimeout(CONNECTION_REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS)
    .setSocketTimeout(SOCKET_TIMEOUT_MS)
    .build();
final CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
    .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig)
    .build();
```

Comment: What are the default values in the Apache code? Are any constants/symbols available?