# How to set time out period for HttpDefaultClient?

Tags: webservices-client

How to set time out period for `HttpDefaultClient`?

For the below code I want to set some time out so that it will not hang for more time.

```
String methodName = "getResponseFromGlobalService";
logger.info(methodName + " started " + "with" + restUrl + "inputs" + jsonObject.toString());
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(restUrl);
StringBuffer outputDocument = new StringBuffer();
StringEntity input1 = new StringEntity(jsonObject.toString());
input1.setContentType("application/json");
postRequest.setEntity(input1);
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);

if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) {
  throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
}

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((response.getEntity().getContent())));

String output;
logger.info("Output from Server .... \n");
while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
  outputDocument.append(output);
}

JSONObject json = (JSONObject) JSONSerializer.toJSON(outputDocument.toString());
logger.info(methodName + " ended ");
return json;
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3000214/java-http-client-request-with-defined-timeout

Comment: Please consider upvoting or accepting the answer if it helped you solved the problem. Otherwise, please provide info. on what isn't working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using DefaultHttpClient 3.x, then the two methods you will need are [HttpConnectionParams.html.setConnectionTimeout()](https://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/params/HttpConnectionParams.html#setSoTimeout(int)) and [HttpConnectionParams.html.setSoTimeout()](https://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/params/HttpConnectionParams.html#setConnectionTimeout(int)), which set the connection timeout and the socket timeout, respectively. The connection timeout is the duration to wait for a connection to be established, while the socket timeout is the duration to wait for the data.

So you will use them like this:

```
HttpConnectionParams httpParams = new HttpConnectionParams();

int connectionTimeout = 30000; // some timeout in milliseconds
httpParams.setConnectionTimeout(connectionTimeout );

int socketTimeout = 30000; // some timeout in milliseconds
httpParams.setSoTimeout(socketTimeout);

DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
```

---

Now if you are using DefaultHttpClient 4.x, (in which case you should be using [HttpClientBuilder](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClientBuilder.html) instead of DefaultHttpClient), then these are the methods that will be relevant:

1. [RequestConfig.Builder.setConnectTimeout](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/config/RequestConfig.Builder.html#setConnectTimeout(int))
2. [RequestConfig.Builder.setSocketTimeout](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/config/RequestConfig.Builder.html#setSocketTimeout())
3. [RequestConfig.Builder.setConnectionTimeout](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/config/RequestConfig.Builder.html#setConnectionRequestTimeout(int))

Here's an example.

```
int connectTimeout = 50000;
int requestTimeout = 50000;
int socketimeout = 50000;
RequestConfig requestConfig = 
    RequestConfig.custom()
        .setConnectTimeout(connectTimeout)
        .setConnectionRequestTimeout(requestTimeout)
        .setSocketTimeout(socketTimeout)
        .build();
HttpClient httpClient = 
    HttpClientBuilder.create()
        .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig )
        .build();
```