# Why selenium test is hanging

Tags: selenium, nightwatch.js

I have a 20 tests that run in parallel. Sometimes one of them hangs. It is not the same test that hangs every time. It seems that the test is make a POST request to Request: POST /wd/hub/session, but its not getting any response back. Does anyone know why test might not get a response back from selenium? How do we debug this or preven this?

Comment: Use global timeout, so that it can exit gracefully if the intended test does not respond.

Comment: what's the global timeout?

Comment: Define a property timeout, similar to the application url. And see example to request timeout - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3000214/java-http-client-request-with-defined-timeout