# How to cancel a thread making a http request from another thread

Tags: java, multithreading, http

Any suggestion on how do we kill a thread which has made a http post request and waiting till getting response. I want to kill this thread from another thread running parallely before it could receive any response from request. I got suggestion to close or abort the http post request but did not workout, can anyone suggest how can we abort the http request in this scenario or any other way to achieve this.

Comment: Try `Thread.interrupt`.

Comment: The only way to stop a Thread is to interrupt it.  Either the Thread’s run method will respond properly to the interrupt, or it won’t.  If it doesn’t, there is nothing else you can do.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3000214/java-http-client-request-with-defined-timeout. Also have you looked at async http?

Comment: Give some more details what http client you use. Do you use a third party library? (eg. Apache HTTP Client) It all depends HOW you do it. Interrupting the thread will wirk in most cases i guess. I suggest you read the documentation of the client you use.

Comment: Based on what I'm reading through native java stuff and javax.ws.rs don't listen for interruptions. Some say that apache HTTP client doesn't either - but this one needs to be double-checked.

Comment: I don't know - for me, it seems that suggested solutions suck in design - why would we let the observer (canceling) threads know the details of the HTTP implementation of the canceled threads? There has to be a way to force both connection and response waiting to quit when the thread is being interrupted...

Comment: Looks like Java v16 introduced cancelable futures which might help if you're okay with cancelling the specific HTTP request thread.
https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8252515

Comment: Also looks like OkHTTP has added support for listening for thread interruptions:
https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/6611

Answer (score 2):

The thread that made the request is blocked while waiting the server to respond. If you take a thread dump and see, it will be in some read() method, but not on a Thread.sleep. So calling interrupt() will not have an effect (unless it's an InterruptibleChannel).
Do you have access to the socket or the output stream on which the POST request was made? If so, you can close that, which will bring out of the read wait with an exception.
Do you have a code sample that you can put up?

Comment: you are right if we do thread.getState() on the thread during the wait for response we will get state as RUNNING. Due to which when interrupt is triggered the interrupt flag of the thread gets set but thread will be killed gracefully after finishing the request.

Comment: Iam using apache http client and I cannot use asynchttp. I tried requesting

Comment: Iam using apache http client and I cannot use asynchttp. I tried using one thread to send the request and ex:ReqThread and cancel listener thread ex:CancelThread and I have a shared variable object holding httpPost object. actual request happens in class A  and it uses httpPost sent by ReqThread for sending request. I have cancel event listening implementation in CancelThread which reads the httpPost set by ReqThreaad in shared object to issue**httppost.abort()**. Here is the problem where Iam getting httpPost object as null.

Answer (score 1):

Helloo everyone, finally got this closing socket idea implemented and working. below is the snippet i tried.

my Requesting thread

```
package com.pkg.myhttptest;

import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;

public class RequestThread implements Runnable{

    Message msg = null;
    Util util = null;
    public RequestThread(Message msg, Util util) {
        this.msg = msg;
        this.util = util;
    }
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("its request thread");
        util.print(msg);
    }



}
```

Cancelling Thread

```
public class CancelThread implements Runnable {
    Message msg = null;
    Util util = null;
    public CancelThread(Message msg, Util util) {
        this.msg = msg;
        this.util = util;
    }
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("its cancel thread");
        int i=0;
        while(i<5){
            System.out.println("looping" + i);
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println(msg.getHttpost() + "In cancelled");
        Header[] hdr = msg.getHttpost().getAllHeaders();
        System.out.println(hdr.length + "length");
        msg.getHttpost().abort();
        System.out.println(msg.getHttpost().isAborted());

    }

}
```

Shared Object

```
public class Message {

    HttpPost httpost;

    public HttpPost getHttpost() {
        return httpost;
    }

    public void setHttpost(HttpPost httpost) {
        this.httpost = httpost;
    }
}
```

Util Class

```
public class Util {
    private final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";

    public void print(Message msg) {
        String url = "https://selfsolve.apple.com/wcResults.do";
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
        HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build(); 
        post.setHeader("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);

        List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sn", "C02G8416DRJM"));
        urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cn", ""));
        urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("locale", ""));
        urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("caller", ""));
        urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("num", "12345"));

        try {
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters));
            msg.setHttpost(post);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
            System.out.println("Response Code : " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

            StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
            String line = "";
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                result.append(line);
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

        } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
```

Main Class

```
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        Message msg = new Message();
        Util util = new Util();

        Thread reqThread = new Thread(new RequestThread(msg, util));
        Thread cancelThread = new Thread(new CancelThread(msg, util));

        System.out.println("Starting Threads");
        reqThread.start();
        try {
            reqThread.sleep(2000);
            cancelThread.start();
            cancelThread.join();
            System.out.println("closing..");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Its little uncleaned code I agree, but it works. It results in below exception and kills the thread.

```
java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
    at java.net.Socket.getInputStream(Socket.java:876)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.doneConnect(SSLSocketImpl.java:644)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.<init>(SSLSocketImpl.java:549)
```

Thanks everyone who has put their efforts in helping me.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to solve the same thing.  I wrote an HTTP Request Runnable that took 20 seconds to timeout and executed on one thread (1st Thread).  I wrote a Timeout Runnable on a separate thread (2nd Thread) that was supposed to interrupt/stop the 1st Thread after 10 seconds.  For every second in the Main Thread (3 threads total), I printed the state of the threads and found the 1st thread kept running.

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

public class A_Test_Thread_Interrupt {
    public static final String URL_THAT_CAUSES_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT_AFTER_20_SECONDS = "https://..."; // Need to provide this for your system.  Must timeout after 20 seconds
//  java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
//  at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
//  at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
//  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
//  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
//  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
//  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
//  at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
//  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
//  at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:542)
//  at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:414)
//  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
//  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:326)
//  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:610)
//  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:445)
//  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835)
//  at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
//  at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108)
//  at A_Test_Thread_Interrupt$HttpRequestRunnable.run(A_Test_Thread_Interrupt.java:35)
//  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("main Start");
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        SharedData sd = new SharedData();

        System.out.println("Starting HTTPS Request Thread");
        HttpRequestRunnable httpRequestRunnable = new HttpRequestRunnable(sd);
        Thread workerThread = new Thread(httpRequestRunnable);
        workerThread.start();

//      workerThread.stop();

        System.out.println("Starting Timeout Thread");
        TimeoutRunnable timeoutRunnable = new TimeoutRunnable(workerThread, httpRequestRunnable, sd);
        Thread timeoutThread = new Thread(timeoutRunnable);
        timeoutThread.start();

        for(int i=0; i<30; i++) {
            System.out.println("workerThread.getState():"+workerThread.getState()+" timeoutThread.getState():"+timeoutThread.getState());

            try { // Sleep for 1 second
                Thread.sleep(1*1000);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("main End timeInSeconds:"+(endTime-startTime)/1000);
    }

    public static class HttpRequestRunnable implements Runnable {

        SharedData sharedData;
        public HttpRequestRunnable (SharedData sharedData) {
            this.sharedData = sharedData;
            sharedData.setIsFinished(this, false);
        }

        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Running HttpRequestRunnable Runner Start");
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            try {
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(URL_THAT_CAUSES_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT_AFTER_20_SECONDS);
                CloseableHttpResponse response = new DefaultHttpClient().execute(httpGet);
                String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                System.out.println("responseString:"+responseString);

                sharedData.setIsFinished(this, true);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("Running HttpRequestRunnable Runner End timeInSeconds:"+(endTime-startTime)/1000);
        }
    }

    public static class SharedData {
        Map<Runnable, Boolean> isFinishedMap = Collections.synchronizedMap(new LinkedHashMap<Runnable, Boolean>());
        public void setIsFinished(Runnable runnable, Boolean value) {
            synchronized(isFinishedMap) {
                isFinishedMap.put(runnable, value);
            }
        }
        public Boolean getIsFinished(Runnable runnable) {
            synchronized(isFinishedMap) {
                return isFinishedMap.get(runnable);
            }
        }
    }

    public static class TimeoutRunnable implements Runnable {
        Thread workerThreadToKillIfItTakesTooLong;
        Runnable runnable;
        SharedData sharedData;
        public TimeoutRunnable(Thread workerThreadToKillIfItTakesTooLong, Runnable runnable, SharedData sharedData) {
            this.workerThreadToKillIfItTakesTooLong = workerThreadToKillIfItTakesTooLong;
            this.runnable = runnable;
            this.sharedData = sharedData;
        }

        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Running TimeoutRunnable Runnable Start");
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            int secondsToSleep = 1;
            int iterationsPerNote = 2;
            int iterations = 10;
            for(int i=0; i<iterations; i++) { // Sleep for at most 10 seconds
                boolean workerRunnableIsFinished = sharedData.getIsFinished(runnable);
                if(workerRunnableIsFinished) {
                    return;
                } else {
                    if(i % iterationsPerNote == 0) { // Print a message every 2 iterations
                        System.out.println("TimeoutRunnable waiting for workerRunnable...");
                    }
                }
                try { // Sleep for 1 second
                    Thread.sleep(secondsToSleep*1000);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            // 5 minutes have passed, kill thread
            System.out.println("Killing worker thread for taking too long");
            workerThreadToKillIfItTakesTooLong.stop();

            sharedData.setIsFinished(runnable, true);

            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("Running TimeoutRunnable Runnable End timeInSeconds:"+(endTime-startTime)/1000);
        }

    }
}
```

Here was the output

```
main: main Start
main: Starting HTTPS Request Thread
main: Starting Timeout Thread
1st_: Running HttpRequestRunnable Runner Start
main: workerThread.getState():RUNNABLE timeoutThread.getState():RUNNABLE
2nd_: Running TimeoutRunnable Runnable Start
2nd_: TimeoutRunnable waiting for workerRunnable...
main: workerThread.getState():RUNNABLE timeoutThread.getState():RUNNABLE
2nd_: TimeoutRunnable waiting for workerRunnable...
main: workerThread.getState():RUNNABLE timeoutThread.getState():RUNNABLE
main: workerThread.getState():RUNNABLE timeoutThread.getState():RUNNABLE
2nd_: TimeoutRunnable waiting for workerRunnable...
main: workerThread.getState():RUNNABLE timeoutThread.getState():RUNNABLE
main: workerThread.getState():RUNNABLE timeoutThread.getState():TIMED_WAITING
2nd_: TimeoutRunnable waiting for workerRunnable...
main: workerThread.getState():RUNNABLE timeoutThread.getState():RUNNABLE
main: workerThread.getState():RUNNABLE timeoutThread.getState():TIMED_WAITING
2nd_: TimeoutRunnable waiting for workerRunnable...
main: workerThread.getState():RUNNABLE timeoutThread.getState():RUNNABLE
main: workerThread.getState():RUNNABLE timeoutThread.getState():TIMED_WAITING
2nd_: Killing worker thread for taking too long
main: workerThread.getState():RUNNABLE timeoutThread.getState():RUNNABLE
2nd_: Running TimeoutRunnable Runnable End timeInSeconds:10
main: workerThread.getState():RUNNABLE timeoutThread.getState():TERMINATED
main: workerThread.getState():RUNNABLE timeoutThread.getState():TERMINATED
main: workerThread.getState():RUNNABLE timeoutThread.getState():TERMINATED
main: workerThread.getState():RUNNABLE timeoutThread.getState():TERMINATED
main: workerThread.getState():RUNNABLE timeoutThread.getState():TERMINATED
main: workerThread.getState():RUNNABLE timeoutThread.getState():TERMINATED
main: workerThread.getState():RUNNABLE timeoutThread.getState():TERMINATED
main: workerThread.getState():RUNNABLE timeoutThread.getState():TERMINATED
main: workerThread.getState():RUNNABLE timeoutThread.getState():TERMINATED
main: workerThread.getState():RUNNABLE timeoutThread.getState():TERMINATED
main: workerThread.getState():RUNNABLE timeoutThread.getState():TERMINATED
main: workerThread.getState():TERMINATED timeoutThread.getState():TERMINATED
main: workerThread.getState():TERMINATED timeoutThread.getState():TERMINATED
main: workerThread.getState():TERMINATED timeoutThread.getState():TERMINATED
main: workerThread.getState():TERMINATED timeoutThread.getState():TERMINATED
main: workerThread.getState():TERMINATED timeoutThread.getState():TERMINATED
main: workerThread.getState():TERMINATED timeoutThread.getState():TERMINATED
main: workerThread.getState():TERMINATED timeoutThread.getState():TERMINATED
main: workerThread.getState():TERMINATED timeoutThread.getState():TERMINATED
main: main End timeInSeconds:30
```

I use a SharedData class to hold information needed by both threads.  By adding the extra information needed to terminate the thread (ie the HttpGet), I can have the monitoring thread do whatever is necessary to actually terminate the thread (ie call httpGet.abort).  This is the modified code (modified lines end with // MOD)

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

public class A_Test_Thread_Interrupt {
    public static final String      public static final String URL_THAT_CAUSES_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT_AFTER_20_SECONDS = "https://..."; // Need to provide this for your system.  Must timeout after 20 seconds
//  java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
//  at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
//  at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
//  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
//  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
//  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
//  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
//  at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
//  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
//  at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:542)
//  at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:414)
//  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
//  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:326)
//  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:610)
//  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:445)
//  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835)
//  at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
//  at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108)
//  at A_Test_Thread_Interrupt$HttpRequestRunnable.run(A_Test_Thread_Interrupt.java:35)
//  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("main Start");
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        SharedData sd = new SharedData();

        System.out.println("Starting HTTPS Request Thread");
        HttpRequestRunnable httpRequestRunnable = new HttpRequestRunnable(sd);
        Thread workerThread = new Thread(httpRequestRunnable);
        workerThread.start();

//      workerThread.stop();

        System.out.println("Starting Timeout Thread");
        TimeoutRunnable timeoutRunnable = new TimeoutRunnable(workerThread, httpRequestRunnable, sd);
        Thread timeoutThread = new Thread(timeoutRunnable);
        timeoutThread.start();

        for(int i=0; i<30; i++) {
            System.out.println("workerThread.getState():"+workerThread.getState()+" timeoutThread.getState():"+timeoutThread.getState());

            try { // Sleep for 1 second
                Thread.sleep(1*1000);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("main End timeInSeconds:"+(endTime-startTime)/1000);
    }

    public static class HttpRequestRunnable implements Runnable {

        SharedData sharedData;
        public HttpRequestRunnable (SharedData sharedData) {
            this.sharedData = sharedData;
            sharedData.setIsFinished(this, false);
        }

        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Running HttpRequestRunnable Runner Start");
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            try {
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(URL_THAT_CAUSES_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT_AFTER_20_SECONDS);
                sharedData.setHttpGet(this, httpGet); // MOD

                CloseableHttpResponse response = new DefaultHttpClient().execute(httpGet);
                String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                System.out.println("responseString:"+responseString);

                sharedData.setIsFinished(this, true);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("Running HttpRequestRunnable Runner End timeInSeconds:"+(endTime-startTime)/1000);
        }
    }

    public static class SharedData {
        Map<Runnable, Boolean> isFinishedMap = Collections.synchronizedMap(new LinkedHashMap<Runnable, Boolean>());
        Map<Runnable, HttpGet> httpGetMap = Collections.synchronizedMap(new LinkedHashMap<Runnable, HttpGet>()); // MOD
        public void setIsFinished(Runnable runnable, Boolean value) {
            synchronized(isFinishedMap) {
                isFinishedMap.put(runnable, value);
            }
        }
        public Boolean getIsFinished(Runnable runnable) {
            synchronized(isFinishedMap) {
                return isFinishedMap.get(runnable);
            }
        }
        public void setHttpGet(Runnable runnable, HttpGet httpGet) { // MOD
            synchronized(httpGetMap) { // MOD
                httpGetMap.put(runnable, httpGet); // MOD
            } // MOD
        } // MOD
        public HttpGet getHttpGet(Runnable runnable) { // MOD
            synchronized(httpGetMap) { // MOD
                return httpGetMap.get(runnable); // MOD
            } // MOD
        } // MOD
    }

    public static class TimeoutRunnable implements Runnable {
        Thread workerThreadToKillIfItTakesTooLong;
        Runnable runnable;
        SharedData sharedData;
        public TimeoutRunnable(Thread workerThreadToKillIfItTakesTooLong, Runnable runnable, SharedData sharedData) {
            this.workerThreadToKillIfItTakesTooLong = workerThreadToKillIfItTakesTooLong;
            this.runnable = runnable;
            this.sharedData = sharedData;
        }

        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Running TimeoutRunnable Runnable Start");
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            int secondsToSleep = 1;
            int iterationsPerNote = 2;
            int iterations = 10;
            for(int i=0; i<iterations; i++) { // Sleep for at most 10 seconds
                boolean workerRunnableIsFinished = sharedData.getIsFinished(runnable);
                if(workerRunnableIsFinished) {
                    return;
                } else {
                    if(i % iterationsPerNote == 0) { // Print a message every 2 iterations
                        System.out.println("TimeoutRunnable waiting for workerRunnable...");
                    }
                }
                try { // Sleep for 1 second
                    Thread.sleep(secondsToSleep*1000);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            // 5 minutes have passed, kill thread
            System.out.println("Killing worker thread for taking too long");
            workerThreadToKillIfItTakesTooLong.stop();

            HttpGet httpGet = sharedData.getHttpGet(runnable); // MOD
            httpGet.abort(); // MOD

            sharedData.setIsFinished(runnable, true);

            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("Running TimeoutRunnable Runnable End timeInSeconds:"+(endTime-startTime)/1000);
        }

    }
}
```

Here was the modified output

```
main: main Start
main: Starting HTTPS Request Thread
main: Starting Timeout Thread
1st_: Running HttpRequestRunnable Runner Start
main: workerThread.getState():RUNNABLE timeoutThread.getState():RUNNABLE
2nd_: Running TimeoutRunnable Runnable Start
2nd_: TimeoutRunnable waiting for workerRunnable...
main: workerThread.getState():RUNNABLE timeoutThread.getState():RUNNABLE
2nd_: TimeoutRunnable waiting for workerRunnable...
main: workerThread.getState():RUNNABLE timeoutThread.getState():RUNNABLE
main: workerThread.getState():RUNNABLE timeoutThread.getState():TIMED_WAITING
main: workerThread.getState():RUNNABLE timeoutThread.getState():RUNNABLE
2nd_: TimeoutRunnable waiting for workerRunnable...
main: workerThread.getState():RUNNABLE timeoutThread.getState():RUNNABLE
main: workerThread.getState():RUNNABLE timeoutThread.getState():RUNNABLE
2nd_: TimeoutRunnable waiting for workerRunnable...
main: workerThread.getState():RUNNABLE timeoutThread.getState():RUNNABLE
2nd_: TimeoutRunnable waiting for workerRunnable...
main: workerThread.getState():RUNNABLE timeoutThread.getState():RUNNABLE
main: workerThread.getState():RUNNABLE timeoutThread.getState():RUNNABLE
2nd_: Killing worker thread for taking too long
main: workerThread.getState():RUNNABLE timeoutThread.getState():RUNNABLE
2nd_: Running TimeoutRunnable Runnable End timeInSeconds:10
main: workerThread.getState():TERMINATED timeoutThread.getState():TERMINATED
main: workerThread.getState():TERMINATED timeoutThread.getState():TERMINATED
main: workerThread.getState():TERMINATED timeoutThread.getState():TERMINATED
main: workerThread.getState():TERMINATED timeoutThread.getState():TERMINATED
main: workerThread.getState():TERMINATED timeoutThread.getState():TERMINATED
main: workerThread.getState():TERMINATED timeoutThread.getState():TERMINATED
main: workerThread.getState():TERMINATED timeoutThread.getState():TERMINATED
main: workerThread.getState():TERMINATED timeoutThread.getState():TERMINATED
main: workerThread.getState():TERMINATED timeoutThread.getState():TERMINATED
main: workerThread.getState():TERMINATED timeoutThread.getState():TERMINATED
main: workerThread.getState():TERMINATED timeoutThread.getState():TERMINATED
main: workerThread.getState():TERMINATED timeoutThread.getState():TERMINATED
main: workerThread.getState():TERMINATED timeoutThread.getState():TERMINATED
main: workerThread.getState():TERMINATED timeoutThread.getState():TERMINATED
main: workerThread.getState():TERMINATED timeoutThread.getState():TERMINATED
main: workerThread.getState():TERMINATED timeoutThread.getState():TERMINATED
main: workerThread.getState():TERMINATED timeoutThread.getState():TERMINATED
main: workerThread.getState():TERMINATED timeoutThread.getState():TERMINATED
main: workerThread.getState():TERMINATED timeoutThread.getState():TERMINATED
main: main End timeInSeconds:30
```