# Need help replacing this method since CoreConnectionPNames is deprecated (org.apache.http.params)

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber-serenity

I am using this method to set CONNECTION_TIMEOUT and SO_TIMEOUT

```
public void setConfig(ContentType contentType, Integer timeout) {
            setConfig(SerenityRest.config()
                    .sslConfig(new SSLConfig().allowAllHostnames().relaxedHTTPSValidation())
                    .httpClient(HttpClientConfig.httpClientConfig()
                    .setParam(CoreConnectionPNames.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, timeout)
                    .setParam(CoreConnectionPNames.SO_TIMEOUT, timeout)))
                    .addHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, contentType.toString());
        }
```

Comment: ehm ... OK? what part is deprecated? Just check the documentation of that method, and it'll tell you what to use instead.

Comment: org.apache.http.params.CoreConnectionPNames is deprecated

Comment: so check the documentation of that class

Comment: Documentation says:

@Deprecated 
public interface CoreConnectionPNames
Deprecated

  org.apache.http.params
  Maven: org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.9 (httpcore-4.4.9.jar)

Comment: No documentation found for org.apache.http.params

Comment: https://javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4/org/apache/http/params/CoreConnectionPNames.html

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't really get what I should use instead

Comment: Deprecated. 
(4.3) use configuration classes provided 'org.apache.http.config' and 'org.apache.http.client.config'

Answer (score 0):

`org.apache.http.params.CoreConnectionPNames` is deprecated and the class was removed.  This prevents you from using the pre-made constants.

According to [Android Developer Reference for `CoreConnectionPNames`](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/params/CoreConnectionPNames):

- The String value for `SO_TIMEOUT` was `"http.socket.timeout"`.

  - according to [the JavaDocs](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4/org/apache/http/params/CoreConnectionPNames.html#SO_TIMEOUT), replacement guidance references `java.net.SocketOptions.SO_TIMEOUT`, but this is an `int` so this may not be proper guidance
- The String value for `CONNECTION_TIMEOUT` was `"http.connection.timeout"`.

  - there is no replacement guidance

Substituting these for the constants or creating your own constants can replace the original constants; however there is no guarantee these settings will be recognized going forward.  [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3000214/java-http-client-request-with-defined-timeout) should provide guidance on how to proceed forward modernizing the timeout.

Broad guidance is to swap to applying `org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig`.

```
RequestConfig.custom().setSocketTimeout(timeout).setConnectTimeout(timeout).build();
```