# Differnence b/w java.net.ConnectException vs org.apache.commons.httpclient.ConnectTimeoutException

Tags: java, http, exception

I am using Apache http client 3 in the multithreaded environment and sending http post request as xml based to other party server.

I can able to simulate in my local system

1. java.net.ConnectException  => when server is down
2. java.net.SocketTimeoutException  => when server accepted my connection and not able to send response back to my application within some time which we configured.

but in the real-time running environment , i have received the new exception like  org.apache.commons.httpclient.ConnectTimeoutException

Questions:

1. what is the difference b/w java.net.ConnectException vs org.apache.commons.httpclient.ConnectTimeoutException
2. how to simulate org.apache.commons.httpclient.ConnectTimeoutException in local system

any inputs will use full.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference between `java.net.ConnectException` (next just `ConnectException`) and `org.apache.commons.httpclient.ConnectTimeoutException` (next just `ConnectTimeoutException`) is that `ConnectException` is thrown when a connection cannot be established to the server, while `ConnectTimeoutException` is thrown when the connection to the server is established but the server takes too long time to respond.

1. You can read more about `ConnectException` [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2F7%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java/net/ConnectException.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876266/java-net-connectexception-connection-refused).
2. As for `ConnectTimeoutException` - [here](https://hc.apache.org/httpclient-legacy/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/ConnectTimeoutException.html) and [here](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.9/org/apache/http/conn/ConnectTimeoutException.html) - I don’t know which exact version you are using.

To simulate `ConnectTimeoutException` in your local system, you can try the following:

1. Start a local server that takes a long time to respond to requests.
2. In your Java code, [set a small connection timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3000214/java-http-client-request-with-defined-timeout) for the **Apache HttpClient** by using the `HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(int timeout)` method.